# "no gate index specified when accessing vector gate 'customer$o'--in module (CSE) CSE_Network.CSE.mn[0]" ? OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I have a problem with OMNeT++ while simulating my protocol in OMNeT++. In my protocol we have to discover some modules connected via different gates. The point where I am getting this error is where I want to explore the modules connected via `customer$o` or `customer$i` gate. Wnen the simulation reaches to that point it stops.
I want to know that is there any way to avoid this error? The allowunconnected in NED doesn't work and also some other built in function like `isConnected`, `getSize` etc. also doesn't work.
The line where I get this error is:

```
int vectSize = gate("customer$o",0)->getVectorSize();
```

Any kind of suggestions are welcomed. I will be thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To read the size of a gate use this method:

```
int vectSize = gateSize("customer");
```

Comment: Thank you that your solution works.. Have a good day..